# Android OnActivityResult gave me a NULL value with getExtras(), although it was set

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get a bitmap inside the onActivityResult from putExtra.getData(), which I fill in beforehand. However, putExtra.getData() is always NULL. And I wonder why

```
 photoFile = createImageFile();

    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            "com.bkoubik.fortestingall.fileprovider",
             photoFile);

       takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
       someActivityResultLauncher.launch(takePictureIntent);


  }


 // You can do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {

                    if(result.getData() != null)
                    {


                        Bundle extras = result.getData().getExtras(); //NULL - WHY ?
                        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                       
                        vorschau.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                    }

                }
            }
 });
```

Comment: If you attach a `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the launch `Intent`, that's where your (full-res) image is. The camera app isn't expected to return a thumbnail bitmap on the result `Intent` when you have that extra.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the prebuilt [`TakePicture` contract](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture), which makes it clear that you do not get any return value out of the Intent you receive back? Or [`TakePicturePreview`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview) which returns you a `Bitmap` thumbnail only?